# Should you italicize names of aircraft if they are serial numbers?

Tags: grammar, proper-nouns, italics

In English, it's customary to italicize the names of vessels, aircraft, and spacecraft, e.g. USS *Oklahoma*, B-17 *Ye Olde Pub*, and space shuttle *Discovery*. Does that also apply to specific aircraft known only by their serial numbers or registration, like Cessna 172 *N344RB* vs N344RB or F-15 *90-0240* vs 90-0240?

Comment: Cessna is a brand name, not the name of a specific plane.

Comment: I'm not talking about the brand name, I'm talking about the registration/serial number of a specific example Cessna.

Comment: Perhaps only in American English? I was mildly surprised to find that Wikipedia does italicise the name of HMS Victory, but [her own website](https://www.nmrn.org.uk/visit-us/portsmouth-historic-dockyard/hms-victory) doesn't. See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/320181/why-are-vessel-names-italicized?rq=1

Comment: There are no rules about this. It's up to the institution you write for.

Answer (score 5):

The [FAA writing guide](https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/order/branding_writing/order1000_36.pdf) doesn't cover this but refers you to the U.S. Government Publishing Office Style Manual, which says **not** to italicize hull numbers; it appears likely the same applies to aircraft registration numbers or serial numbers.

In the [2016 GPO Style Manual](https://www.govinfo.gov/collection/gpo-style-manual?path=/gpo/U.S.%20Government%20Publishing%20Office%20Style%20Manual/2016) it says "The names of aircraft, vessels, and manned spacecraft are italicized unless otherwise indicated." It then gives a list of examples. Those italicized include

- USS *Wisconsin*
- *Apollo 13*, *Atlantis* (U.S. spaceships)
- *Enola Gay*

Those not italicized include

- Air Force One (President’s plane)
- B–50 (type of plane)
- DD–882
- LST–1155
- MiG, MiG–35

Of those, DD–882 and LST–1155 are US Navy hull classification numbers. In view of how the same principles hold across ships, aircraft, and spacecraft, the same rules can be applied to aircraft. (The idea that italicization would depend on whether the plane has another name is a little bizarre.)

This is supported by the majority of websites, e.g. the style guide of [1000 Aircraft Photos](https://1000aircraftphotos.com/DesignationSystem.html).

Comment: Correspondingly, Wikipedia has  << BR Standard Class 8 71000 _Duke of Gloucester_  >>. Either appositive (the non-italicised identification number / the italicised name) may be dropped.

Comment: This is the standard practice, but one can't help wondering whether there is some rationale for it, or it is completely arbitrary. I suppose that what motivates the OP's question is that registration numbers, in many ways, perform the same function as names.

Answer (score 0):

I can't cite a definitive rule on this, but as someone who's read a lot about aircraft, I would say no.

Wikipedia does not italicize serial numbers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_surviving_North_American_P-51_Mustangs#United_States

Comment: Style manuals probably cover this.